# Can latent class analysis be used for path analysis?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, latent-class

I have been experimenting with latent class analysis (LCA), which I've recently learned is a form of structural equation modeling (SEM). I know some forms of SEM, I know path analysis can be done where a structural model and a measurement model.

Can LCA be used as part of this path analysis? If so, what's a good resource / example of this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can. It's pretty tricky to parameterize.

I believe that the Mplus manual has examples, and there's also this paper by David Kaplan: https://www.statmodel.com/download/Dkaplan.MarkovModels.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Having a latent categorical variable as outcome of a path analysis is standard within the Mplus package. Bengt Muthen, one of Mplus' authors, pioneered incorporating latent categorical variables within the SEM framework in the 1980s.

[Here is one example](http://statmodel.com/examples/categorical/cat5.html)

Yes, you do run into special problems. You can start to get a sense of those from the [Mplus manual](http://statmodel.com/ugexcerpts.shtml). The availability of this functionality varies greatly by package.